# Picture of lower quality

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to express following:

> Pictures on site xyz.com are [word].

With meaning **pictures are of lower quality**, I always thought that correct term is "*rasterized*" or "*pixelated*".

For example pictures uploaded on blue social site are pre-processed which results in pictures being of lower quality (where you can clearly see pixelation/rasterisation).

While I was looking around to find correct term (mostly on OS X dictionary application), rasterisation is:

> convert (an image stored as an outline) into pixels that can be displayed on a screen or printed. the driver uses these commands to rasterize the page.

---

Bonus

Is rasteri**z**e UK english and rasteri**s**e US english? I can not find that information anywhere.

Comment: Low *resolution* might work, except that you're probably talking about (re)compression artifacts. The more generic *low quality*, as you have it, is a good description.

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you for stopping by, I am probably biased towards "highly rasterized" because its common use in my own language (translated of course) which means of lower quality. I guess that does not even makes sense in English.

Comment: In modern internet slang -- and I'm not making this up, I promise -- the word is *potato*. As in "what did you take Jose photos with, a potato*?

Comment: @DanBron Oh of course, one might say a *calculator*, "what did you take Jose photos with, a calculator?"; I am more interested in a way to express low quality no matter how picture is produced.

Comment: @Kyslik No, I mean the actual idiomatic term, the word used to express low-quality images in contemporary vernacular on the web, is actually and specifically *potato* and not any other word.

Comment: @Kyslik Do you have a specific form of low quality that you're trying to describe? Otherwise, is there something about the term 'low quality' that you don't like? Pictures can be of low quality in many ways - banding, jpeg blockiness, poor contrast, extreme contrast, fuzziness, etc.

Comment: @DanBron Hmm I looked that up [*Potato, derogatory slang associated with poor-quality cameras.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_(disambiguation)) As I am saying facebook does produce potato like images but I can not take potato as scientific/professional term :D

Comment: @DanBron Then again, there's [this](https://petapixel.com/2016/01/21/this-photo-of-a-potato-sold-for-over-1000000/) potato photo. :)

Comment: @Lawrence I want to express this kind of quality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact#/media/File:Sego_lily_cm-150.jpg

Comment: @Kyslik If it related to *characters*, you could call it [*aliasing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). It's a signal-processing (technical) term, less commonly used with pictures, I think. I'd suggest *compression artifacts* as the best match for a technical term, except that it doesn't go with your sample sentence.

Comment: Why  not just say the pictures are "fuzzy" or "unclear"?

Comment: This is a technical question. Rasterize is not the word you want as it means convert from vector graphics to bitmap graphics (e.g. from Illustrator to Photoshop) and a rasterized image can be of adequate quality for the web or even for printing. There are many different types of low quality and I would really need a link to the site to be able to analyse the pics and give you an answer. They could be badly composed, fuzzy because of camera shake, pixelated because a 72 dpi pic has been enlarged, show jpeg artifacts etc. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're referring to [compression artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact). The pictures can be described as *degraded*.

> **degraded** *adjective*
>   1.1 Reduced in quality; inferior.
>   ‘It is necessary to design the antenna properly or system performance will be degraded.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/degraded)

Here are a couple of examples of the term in use:

- A quality setting of 100 does not degrade an image at all: False
  [- JPEG Myths and Facts, ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/jpeg-myths-and-facts-1701548)
- If it's saved and closed again, compression removes yet more quality, and so on as the image gradually degrades.
  [- JPEG Image Compression Degradation, patricktaylor.com](http://www.patricktaylor.com/1940)

Your sample sentence would be:

- Pictures on site xyz.com are *degraded*.

Answer (score 3):

### Potato-quality answer

The standard term in contemporary internet vernacular to describe low-quality images is:

> #### Potato

It sounds absurd, and it is, intentionally (we live in a very sarcastic age), but this is the standard term on the web.

### No, I'm not kidding

Per [the Internet-slang dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/potato-quality):

> #### potato quality
>
> *adjective*
>
> of a photo, poor quality. From a photo looking like it was taken with a potato.
>
> > Sorry for the potato quality photos of the birthday party.
> >     See more words with the same meaning: bad, poor, sucks, common, generally displeasing.

From the internet-trend documenting site [KnowYourMeme's entry on the meme *potato*](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/recorded-with-a-potato):

> "Recorded with a Potato” is a phrase commonly found in YouTube comments criticizing the resolution of a video that appears heavily pixelated or blurry.

From Reddit, the gazed-navel of the internet, [on the same subject](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/1sduz4/comment/cdww9vu?st=J4IBRNW6&sh=37164b61):

> It's ... a joke that their camera is so low tech, it's equivalent to a non technological item like a potato.

[And](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/1sduz4/comment/cdxfjb3?st=J4IBR843&sh=dfea50a0)

> See also the B3ta website, where "potatoshop" or "potatochop" was often used for low quality image manipulations, often followed by someone exclaiming "Seamless!".
>
> This was happening in at least 2003.
>
> Google searches show it happening in like 2002.

[And](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/1sduz4/comment/cdwla53?st=J4IBQSGD&sh=c76e0b66)

> The story behind it is that potatoes don't take very good photos.

### Lifestyles of the rich and shameless

The usage is so widespread that this *high*-quality image of a potato:

[image: quality potato image]

was bought by an Silicon-Valley internet-tech millionaire for [over a million dollars](https://petapixel.com/2016/01/21/this-photo-of-a-potato-sold-for-over-1000000/). *Ironically*.

Welcome to the internet.

---

<sub>Credit to [@Lawrence for finding this article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396367/picture-of-lower-quality#comment940119_396367)</sub>

Comment: So you think "**Pictures on site xyz.com are potatoes.**" sounds sane?

Comment: I have never heard the term used this way.

Comment: @Kyslik It's not that it's sane. It's that it's *standard* ;)

Comment: I am having a good laugh, thank you :); I will probably use **low quality** or such; **potato** won the day (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

The pictures on xyz.com are of low resolution.

Or in general, if they are not of low resolution, low quality works fine.

Comment: Mate you really got me with that name! I was literally waiting for loading to finish... Thank you for an answer.